# .NET application design with multiple line-of-business databases

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, integration

Core company data is held and managed in physically separate, third-party, line-of-business applications: Finance, Transport Management. Customers are created in the Finance app (SQL Server), delivery information is held in the Transport Management app (Oracle). Communication between the two is point-to-point.

We need to build a new application (well upgrade the old one, but essentially from scratch) to process customer claims for damaged or short deliveries. Claims, customer and delivery data is currently manually entered in to MS Access. This will be migrated to a SQL server DB. The app development platform is VS2008 (C#).

I would like to avoid having all of the customer and delivery data in the claims database, since we already hold it elsewhere, so I plan to produce WCF based  feeds from the LOB systems (and possibly the claims db) which can then be used as the data sources for the customer claims app. There will be claim-specific data entry but the core customer and delivery data would not need to be updated in the LOB apps.

So far I have in mind

> database-->ORM-->WCF \
>   database-->ORM-->WCF    --->BLL-->UI
>   database-->ORM-->WCF /

but it feels wrong as I will be creating separate service feeds for Customers, Deliveries and Claims (object-oriented services?). What I also can't quite grasp is how and where I join and work across data sources within the app to produce, say, a report showing claims against deliveries per customer (i.e. where I would traditionally write a query or view to get all of this from multiple tables in one DB).

Am I on the right track or I am missing the big picture here - should I just run regular extracts in to a claims db and work with traditional n-tier / n-layer architecture?

Comment: One question to help clarify the problem... Do you see the Finance and Transport apps using the WCF services as well or just the claims app?

Comment: The likelihood that we will update our core LOB systems via services seems a long way off at present, but other apps will need to consume finance and transport data - e.g. a returns app, KPI reports, customer portal apps. This is really one example of the general state of things within the business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your design is too far off from where it should be.

If you have apps that will access finance data via the WCF service or the Transport service, those make sense to build.  They also make sense to build because each of those services just supports what it needs to know about (ties in with the Single Responsibility Principle).

Where it might not feel right is where your UI app needs to know about and call 3 separate services to get its job done.  In situations like that we've often built a wrapper service that makes the call to the appropriate service.  Meaning your UI app would reference a WCF service and that service would then call the Finance service or the Transport service or the Claims service.  Downside - each call results in multiple calls... yes.  But it abstracts the logic away from your UI app and provides the benefit of giving you a place to manipulate or combine data from the other services or to add other business logic that is appropriate for the app.  You also still have the benefit of the Finance service still supporting the finance apps without your UI app's business needs getting in the way or muddying up the code for its benefit.

I'm sure that there are different solution paths for this.  This is just how we've handled in a couple of applications.

**EDIT**  (answering your follow up question took too much space to make a comment).

If the data you can get from the Transport service is enough to satisfy the question that is asked by saying "getCustomerDelieveries" then no I wouldn't break it out to another wrapper service.  If you need more data, then what other apps would also benefit from that service providing more customer information?  Do those apps rely soley on the Transport service?  This is one of those where the answer has to "feel" right to you, since you know the most about your systems.

Perhaps you need to break the SRP rule and have your Transport service get more customer information from the finance db or service.  Or if apps that rely on the Transport service routinely need more customer data then thought could be given to expanding the customer table in the Transport db.

No rule, principle or philosophy should be applied so rigidly that you can't break it if it makes more sense for your app.  It's going to be a balance and there is no right or wrong answer, just what works better for this situation.

You started this post by talking about a new UI app that would support the Claims part of your business and it needed both Finance and Transport data (as well as its own).  That is a perfect candidate to call a wrapper service.  It needs data from 3 distinct and separate data sources.  Your Transport service has limited customer information which works well for some apps but perhaps not so well for others.  If you write a wrapper service that mirrors your Transport service 100% and additionally provides a bit more customer data, what have you gained?  More data for the apps that consume it but also more maintainance for you whenever you add functionality to the Transport service.  What other value could this wrapper provide?

In this case, to me, having the Transport service get more customer data from the Finance service "feels" better.  Your Transport db has some data but not enough.  It's almost like the Transport service needs to make up for this short coming by fufilling the data need itself.

Comment: OK, Transport (deliveries) and Finance (customers) services help with my confusion over service granularity. Since there is already point-to-point integration to add customers to the transport LOB, would you treat, say, getCustomerDeliveries() as a pure Transport Service method or would you move away from this to apply SRP and write another wrapper to join Customers from the Finance Service with Deliveries from the Tranport Service?

Comment: Good question.  How are customers handled in the Transport db?  Just a key or is the data duplicated since they're in separate db's?

Comment: A key common to both dbs and "enough" duplicated data for the Transport system (no invoicing, head office details, etc) - the point-to-point is one way from Finance to Transport.

Answer (score 0):

When generating reports, it's usually tolerable to deliver not most up-to-date data, so it may be a good idea to dedicate separate DB as source for reporting queries. Your master DBs will receive updates from UI (taking advantage of transactions and conflicts detection) and then replicate data to reporting DB.

This architectural pattern is called CQS (Command Query Separation), read this [great article](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/08/11/command-query-separation-and-soa/) by Udi Dahan.

Comment: Good point Dmitry, this has worked well for me in the past but this is a business application, one of the outputs of which will be a report. There would be other (CRUD) functionality required also.

Comment: This approach still allows running simple queries on master DBs. Reporting DB is used, for example, when you have to join customers table with deliveries which are stored in separate DBs. It would be unnatural and expensive to do this in the service layer.

Comment: Interesting article that you referenced, but I think the sheer scale of this one puts it out of scope for the moment. One to revisit when our BI project is a little more mature, perhaps, or when we get around to offering service APIs to customers. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I should use an orchestration service with WWF (or other orchestration tool).

I like this view:

DAL, BLL, SIL --> WCf1
DAL, BLL, SIL --> WCF2

wcf1 and wcf2 are joined by an orchestration service over them. This way the services remains autonomous and decoupled, and you could reuse them in other orchestrations.

Comment: SIL - Service Integration Layer? So the WCF1 and WCF2 are essentially LOB adapters and the consuming app (Claims in this case) has an orchestration layer, or are you talking about a middleware / ESB type solution?

Comment: well, it is up to you. You could have some kind of MVC layer in the application, or you can do just an orchestration service (just another service) or put a full esb in the middle. Depends of future extensibility an connection of your system.